# r - How to translate this time series calculation into a raster calculation?

Tags: r, raster

I'm trying to reproduce this vector (time series) calculation code:

`gamma.parameters<-  fitdistr(may_baseline_3months[may_baseline_3months>0],"gamma")`

into a raster calculation code.

What this code originally does is trying to fit a gamma distribution by maximum likelihood estimation to a vector (time series) `may_baseline_3months`.

And what I want to do is to calculate the same thing but with a raster stack.

I tried doing this with `calc()` function:

`f1<-function(x)
{
  library(MASS)
  return(fitdistr(x,"gamma"))
}
gamma.parameters<-  calc(x = may_baseline_3months,fun = f1)`

`Error in .calcTest(x[1:5], fun, na.rm, forcefun, forceapply) : 
cannot use this function`

but it didn't work.
Note: My raster stack has only 4 layer.

***EDIT***

You can download a example data here [spi](http://crc-osa.ciifen.org/images/images/portada/monitoreo/oceano/TSM/global/guatemala_spi.csv)

The fitdistr is part of the procedure of my main goal. I'm trying to calcule the Standard Precipitation Index. I already did it with a time series of a monthly precipitation of 30 year.

Here is the code for a time series till the line that I'm stock:

```
data<-read.csv("guatemala_spi.csv",header = T,sep=";")

dates<-data[,1]
rain_1month<-data[,2]
rain_3months<-0
#Setting the first 2 elements to NA because I'm going to calcule the accumulating the rainfall for 3 month
for (i in c(1:2)) {
  rain_3months[i]<-NA
}
#Accumulating the rainfall for the rest of the data
number_of_months<-length(rain_1month)
for (j in c(3:number_of_months)) 
{
 rain_3months[j]<-0.0
 for (i in c(0:2)) 
{
 rain_3months[j] = rain_3months[j] + rain_1month[j-i]
}
}
#Extracting a time-series for the month of interest (May)
may_rain_3months<-rain_3months[substr(dates,5,6)==”05”]
dates_may<-dates[substr(dates,5,6)==”05”]
number_of_years<-length(dates_may) 

#Fitting the gama distribution by maximum likelihood estimation 
start_year<-1971
end_year<-2010
start_index<-which(substr(dates_may,1,4)==start_year)
end_index<-which(substr(dates_may,1,4)==end_year)
may_baseline_3months<-may_rain_3months[start_index:end_index] 

library(MASS)
gamma.parameters<-fitdistr(may_baseline_3months[may_baseline_3months>0],"gamma")
```

That last line is the one that I'm having problems to calculate for a raster stack.

Here's what I have so far in raster form:

Example multi-layer raster  [here](http://crc-osa.ciifen.org/images/images/portada/monitoreo/oceano/TSM/global/chirps_rain_1month.tif)  (Monthly precipitation 2001 to 2004, 48 layers in total)

```
#Initiating a dates vector
dates<-c("200101","200102","200103","200104","200105","200106","200107","200108","200109","200110","200111","200112",
    "200201","200202","200203","200204","200205","200206","200207","200208","200209","200210","200211","200212",
    "200301","200302","200303","200304","200305","200306","200307","200308","200309","200310","200311","200312",
    "200401","200402","200403","200404","200405","200406","200407","200408","200409","200410","200411","200412")
#Initiating a NA raster
rain_3months_1layer<-raster(nrow=1600, ncol=1673,extent(-118.4539, -34.80395, -50, 30),res=c(0.05,0.05))
values(rain_3months_1layer)<-NA

#Creating a raster stack NA of 48 layers
rain_3months<-stack(mget(rep( "rain_3months_1layer" , 48 )))

#Reading the data
rain_1month <- stack("chirps_rain_1month.tif")

#Accumulating the rainfall
number_of_months<-nlayers(rain_1month)
for (j in c(3:number_of_months)) 
{
 rain_3months[[j]]<-0.0
 for (i in c(0:2)) 
 {
 rain_3months[[j]] = rain_3months[[j]] + rain_1month[[j-i]]
 }
}

#Extracting the raster for the month of interest (May)
may_rain_3months<-stack(rain_3months[[which(substr(dates,5,6)=="05", arr.ind = T)]])
dates_may<-dates[substr(dates,5,6)=="05"]
number_of_years<-length(dates_may)

#Fitting the gama distribution by maximum likelihood estimation 
start_year<-2001
end_year<-2004
start_index<-which(substr(dates_may,1,4)==start_year)
end_index<-which(substr(dates_may,1,4)==end_year)
may_baseline_3months<-stack(may_rain_3months[[start_index:end_index]])

library(MASS)

f1<-function(x)
{
library(MASS)
return(fitdistr(x,"gamma"))
}
gamma.parameters<-  calc(x = may_baseline_3months,fun = f1)
```

I can't make `calc()` to compute `fitdistr()` to the raster stack.

Comment: I've deleted the rstudio tags since they are irrelevant (this is plain R) and added a raster tag. Can you make a reproducible example that we can all run?

Comment: Thanks for you replay! I added an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make a function that `calc` can use. Your function `f1` returns an object of class `fitdistr`. The `calc` function does not know what to do with that:

```
library(MASS)
set.seed(0)
x <- runif(10)

f1 <- function(x) {
  return(fitdistr(x,"gamma"))
}

a <- f1(x)
class(a)
# [1] "fitdistr"
a
#    shape       rate  
#  4.401575   6.931571 
# (1.898550) (3.167113)
```

You need a function that returns numbers. Like `f2`:

```
f2 <- function(x) {
  fitdistr(x,"gamma")$estimate
}

b <- f2(x)

class(b)
#[1] "numeric"
b
#   shape     rate 
#4.401575 6.931571
```

Test `f2` with `calc`:

```
library(raster)
s <- stack(lapply(1:12, function(i) setValues(r, runif(ncell(r)))))
r <- calc(s, f2)
```

I assume that this answers your questions. I cannot be sure because your question is way too complex. The first thing you need to do with a problems like this is to create a simple example like I have done above.

**Next question**

> Error in stats::optim(x = c(7, 7, 7, 7), par = list(shape = Inf, rate
>   = Inf), : non-finite value supplied by optim.

That is a different issue, you are providing `fitdistr` with values it cannot deal with. You can add a `try` clause to skip over those. You could identify which cells this happens in and what the values are to see if there is something else you should do.

```
f3 <- function(x) {
  x <- try (fitdistr(x,"gamma")$estimate, silent=TRUE )
  if (class(x) == 'try-error') { c(-9999, -9999) } else { x }
}

x[1] <- NA
f2(x)
#Error in fitdistr(x, "gamma") : 'x' contains missing or infinite values
f3(x) 
#[1] -9999 -9999
```

Note that you need to make sure that the number of values returned by `f3` should always be the same. In this case two values. Here I use `-9999` so that you can identify the cells. You can also use `NA`

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I want but now I have this problem `Error in stats::optim(x = c(7, 7, 7, 7), par = list(shape = Inf, rate = Inf),  : 
  non-finite value supplied by optim`.

Comment: I have added a response to your follow up question above